# Updating SSRS Report Breaks Subscriptions with Dependent Parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that requires several parameters that cascade from each other. So Dropdown list B is generated when dropdown list A value is chosen. When new values come into the report it breaks an existing user's subscription's when the report causes new values to populate in one of the dropdowns. The user is subscribed with pre-chosen values they want. How can I fix this?

Comment: Forgot to post the error "Failure writing file XXXX for <Report Name> : Default value or value provided for the report parameter '<report value>' is not a valid value."

Answer (score 0):

This error is pretty self-explanatory. Look at the **Default Values** for the parameter it's referring to. You either:

A. Specified the wrong data-type.

OR

B. You specified a value that wasn't in the **Available Values** tab. (most likely)